# Deedle's Frame.ReadCsv "not intended for use from F#". What else then?

Tags: f#, deedle

I'm getting this warning when using `Frame.ReadCsv`. What is the alternative?

Comment: It's possible that this issue would be solved by having updated [F# tools VSIX](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/wiki/Using-CI-Builds). If not file an issue on Deedle's github. For example I can use `Frame.ReadCsv` For an overview see this [post](https://github.com/vasily-kirichenko/fsharpblog/blob/master/index.md). Ideally an official vsix would be published by MS soon...